# Firestore get() -> send custom value to use in a read security rule's get()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-applications, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to send a device id to validate a read request, but how to pass it if it's not part of the request path?

When the info I need is in the request path I can use this form:

```
match /apps-data/{app} {
  allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.subscriptions[app] == true
}
```

But what about using a custom value, like `device`:

```
if exists(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.devices[device])
```

Is it possible at all, is there another way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass along custom data during a get() that can be referenced in security rules.

Even if the id was in the path of the document, you should be aware that this is inherently insecure, as a compromised client could simply fake that data at the time of the request.

Comment: Thank you. The "security" side is not critical, I just wanted a way to prevent super easy access to an app (without a subscription) by account sharing, but yeah, thinking of it, getting the subscriber device id would not be much trouble to someone motivated...